# Why does changing the limit in this SPARQL question make the query yield a server error?

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

This SPARQL query at query.wikidata.org about people born in Sweden in the 1900s or later with more than 3 sitelinks currently gives 6746 results in around 35 s. It takes a long time to run because of the complicated path P19/P131*/P17?.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?person ?dob ?linkcount WHERE {
    ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
    ?person wdt:P19/wdt:P131*/wdt:P17? wd:Q34.
    ?person wdt:P569 ?dob.
    FILTER(datatype(?dob)=xsd:dateTime
           && ?dob >= "1900-01-01T00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime).
    ?person wikibase:sitelinks ?linkcount. hint:Prior hint:rangeSafe true. # hint:Prior hint:runLast true.
    FILTER(?linkcount > 3).
}
```

(Try it [here](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fperson%20%3Fdob%20%3Flinkcount%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ5.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP19%2Fwdt%3AP131%2A%2Fwdt%3AP17%3F%20wd%3AQ34.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP569%20%3Fdob.%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%28datatype%28%3Fdob%29%3Dxsd%3AdateTime%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%26%26%20%3Fdob%20%3E%3D%20%221900-01-01T00%3A00%3A00%22%5E%5Exsd%3AdateTime%29.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fperson%20wikibase%3Asitelinks%20%3Flinkcount.%20hint%3APrior%20hint%3ArangeSafe%20true.%20%23%20hint%3APrior%20hint%3ArunLast%20true.%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%28%3Flinkcount%20%3E%203%29.%0A%7D).)

If I change the linkcount limit from 3 to 30 I instead get a server error after some time. How can that be? I expected a smaller result in about the same time.

The only reason I could think of is that the optimizer erroneously thinks that because of the tighter bounds on number of sitelinks it makes sense to first get all objects having more than 30 sitelinks. (I don't know how to test that hypothesis. I've made a "`/bigdata/namespace/wdq/sparql?explain&query=`" link for that query, but get no result. (Note that I didn't get a timeout from the query that didn't work, but a server error. Is something bad happening while the optimizer is running?)

Then I activated the `hint:runLast` hint that is commented away in my example so that the part about sitelinks will be done last. With `?linkcount > 3` it takes about the same time as before, but the version with `?linkcount > 30` still results in a server error.

I thought that the filter then would be tested last, so that the full list would be constructed anyway, and the number of sitelinks would be retrieved for all those objects, and then filtering should take the same time regardless of the limit. That is evidently wrong. What is actually happening here?

Comment: I can't answer why, but did you try a subquery? `SELECT DISTINCT ?person ?dob ?linkcount WHERE {
  hint:SubQuery hint:runOnce true .
  {select ?person ?dob {
    ?person wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
    ?person wdt:P19/wdt:P131/wdt:P17? wd:Q34.
    ?person wdt:P569 ?dob.
    FILTER(datatype(?dob)=xsd:dateTime
           && ?dob >= "1900-01-01T00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime).
  }
}
  
    ?person wikibase:sitelinks ?linkcount. hint:Prior hint:rangeSafe true. # hint:Prior hint:runLast true.
    FILTER(?linkcount > 30).
}`

Comment: I suppose changing 3 to 30 affects the `wikibase:sitelinks` pattern selectivity; and static optimizer changes execution order. Yes, the complicated path is problematic. Also, `rangeSafe`+`runLast` should be useless, there should be `runFirst`.